# notepad ++ - User defined language "If" found in every word

Tags: notepad++, user-defined

I've created a user defined language, but the "if" condition is found also inside the normal text, or variable names. Is there a way to define that is has to be coupled with "if ..... Then"?

[image]

i tried:

- if then
- "if * then"
- if * then
- {if then}
- {if * then}
- "if "
- If && then

Answer (score 1):

Solved! the keywords need to be in "folding in code 2 style"